# When I am the subject and the direct object of a phrase

Tags: translation-check, syntax, declension, french

I want to translate the following French quote from Paul Valéry:

> *Je ne suis pas toujours d'accord avec moi-même*.

Which roughly translates into:

> I don't always agree with myself.

I want it to be as short as possible. So I thought the best way would be to omit the subject and to use *ego* in the accusative case, which seems to be *me*

That would be something like:

> *Non semper me conveniunt*.

Is that correct? Is it understandable? Is it a nice form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your central question seems to be about the general case ("How do I translate reflexive first person"), here is a more general answer that builds on the above suggestions: **A simple *me* is all that is necessary, but there are ways to emphasize the reflexive pronoun if you wish.**

1. One way, given by Joonas, is to use *ipse*.

   - You can append *ipsum* after *me*:

   > Ergo ista, inquit Crassus, quae habes a me, non reprehendo, **ne me ipsum inrideam.** (Cicero, *De Oratore* 3.47)
   >
   > <sup>Crassus said: "Therefore I do not blame you for those things which you have received from me, **lest I make a mockery of myself.**"</sup>

   - You can also use *ipse*, agreeing with the understood *ego*.

   > sed non egeo medicina, **me ipse consolor** (Cicero, *Laelius de Amicitia* 10.10)
   >
   > <sup>But I have no need of medicine: **I can comfort myself.**</sup>
2. You can also use an emphatic *-met* at the end of the pronoun:

   > neque, ita me di ament, **credebam primo mihimet** Sosiae,
   >   donec Sosia illic egomet fecit sibi uti crederem. (Plautus, *Amphitruo* II.i)
   >
   > <sup>Nor, by all that is good and holy, **did I believe myself**, Sosia, at first
   >
   >   until Sosia made it so that I believed him.</sup>

   (It's difficult to translate this passage out of its context: Mercury takes on the appearance of Sosia, a slave, and manages to convince Sosia that he is the real Sosia: I recommend the play!)
3. You can just use *me* alone if you don't feel a need to emphasize the reflexivity.

   > ubi ille ábiit, **ego me deorsum duco** de arbore. (Plautus, *Aulularia* IV.viii)
   >
   > <sup>When he left, **I let myself down** from the tree.</sup>

The point is that Latin only has a special reflexive pronoun for the third-person: you can use *me* regardless of the subject. In fact, all the "emphatic methods" above could be used just as easily if it was *not* reflexive.

For your actual quote, my translation agrees substantially with Joonas's, though *adsentior* sounds better to my ear:

> Non semper mihi adsentior.
>   Non semper mihimet adsentior.
>   Non semper mihi ipse adsentior.
>   Non semper mihi ipsi adsentior.

Answer (score 4):

The shortest that I can think of is *Aliquando a me dissentio*, 'sometimes I disagree with myself.'

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed shorter, but conveys a slightly different meaning.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest this:

> *Non semper mihi ipsi consentio.*
>   I do not always agree with myself.

You could also use *assentio(r)* instead of *consentio*.
To compare the two, you can check an [online Latin dictionary of your preference](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).

In cases like this I would use *me ipsum / mihi ipsi / …* (depending on the needed case) for "myself".

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't have thought I'd be so close. My Latin is very rusty. So I would go for "non semper mihi ipsi assentio"

Comment: @GéraudBenazet You're welcome! This site is just the place to get the rust off of one's Latin.